# functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code2 "import issue"

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, deployment

I am following a tutorial on how to get Started with Cloud Functions for Firebase using TypeScript. I am currently stuck on the deploying firebase step. **Here is a pic of what it looks like in Vscode**[image]

**Here is the error I am getting**
C:\Users\asr\functions>firebase deploy

```
=== Deploying to 'myapp'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> lint
> eslint --ext .js,.ts .


C:\Users\asr\functions\src\index.ts
  1:13  warning  'functions' is defined but never used  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars

✖ 1 problem (0 errors, 1 warning)

Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run build

> build
> tsc

src/index.ts:1:1 - error TS6133: 'functions' is declared but its value is never read.

1 import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Found 1 error.


Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code2
```

I don't know why the import is giving an error. How can I fix it so that I can deploy my app?

Answer (score 0):

I too face this issue , Kindly check the path of terminal to run your project.
Then deploy the function , it will deploy completely.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).